# Read from a file which is being actively written to

Tags: c

I have two programs: one (`program1`) writes to a file continuously, and I want the other program (`program2`) to read the file continuously. What is happening is that my second program is only reading up to the data point which was written when the second code was executed and stops instead of continuously reading.

Is there any way to achieve the thing?

Basically, I want the output of `program1` to be used as the input of `program2`. Is there any way to read and write in RAM instead of file as disk read costs more time.

Code 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    FILE *fptr;

    fptr = fopen("gbbct1.seq","r");

    char c;
    c = fgetc(fptr);

    while (c != EOF){

        printf("%c", c);
        c = fgetc(fptr);

    }

}
```

I am looking for platform independent approach. If that's not possible, I would like to know for Linux platform.   I don't need to preserve the data once read. I don't want to block `program1`.

Comment: `tail -f`?  It can be done, but we can't fix your code because you've not shown us your code.  Are you using file streams (`FILE *`) or file descriptors (`int`) in `program2`?  The ways you deal with the problem are different, because the sets of functions in use are different.  You **must** show your best effort code — in the form of an MCVE ([MCVE]).  It would also be worth reporting which platform you're on — the answer for Windows is probably different from the answer for POSIX-ish (Unix-like) systems.

Comment: Note, too, that if you're writing to disk, you'll have to make sure that `program1` flushes its output file stream appropriately, if it uses file streams, so that the data is available to `program2` in a timely manner.  If you want to do without disk, you'll need to think about using shared memory, or something similar. That will be harder to set up, and has a finite (and relatively small) size. OTOH, if you're only going to read the data once and don't need it preserved, maybe that's sensible. Or what about a pipe, or FIFO? These could cause `program1` to block if you're not careful, though.

Comment: Bug 1: `fgetc()` returns an `int`, not a `char` — remember that.  Use `int c;` always. When the code encounters EOF, you need to use `clearerr(fptr)` to clear the EOF status.  But if you try again immediately, you'll get EOF again immediately.  So, you'll need to sleep for a bit.  You can't use `poll()` or `select()` because disk files are always ready to read — those only work with pipes, terminals, FIFOs, sockets, and maybe some other character special or block special devices.

Comment: http://www.sanfoundry.com/c-program-illustrate-reading-datafile/ in this example they are using fgetc for character.I think integer is typecasted by default as i am getting output

Comment: Unfortunately, sleeping is a platform-dependent operation.  On Linux et al, you have a super-abundance of choices, including: [`sleep()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sleep.html),
[`usleep()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/usleep.html),
[`nanosleep()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nanosleep.html),
[`alarm()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/alarm.html),
[`pause()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pause.html) and others too.

Comment: But the problem is program 2 only reads the data which was written until its execution start data written later is ignored

Comment: On Windows, you have `Sleep()` for sure and probably others too.  Are you sure you only want `program2` to write to standard output?  You'll need to consider whether the default line-buffered output is appropriate. Line buffering means that the output is flushed when a newline is printed.

Comment: I already told you to use `clearerr()` and a sleep — that's pretty much what's necessary.  There might be a Linux specific way (inotify, perhaps) to get information about when the input file changes so that `program2` can pull in the change.  But that's even less platform-neutral.  The `clearerr()` is platform neutral (mandated by the C standard).  The sleep is platform dependent — but you can code around that.

Comment: I wrote the mentioned code to just show the example of how i am reading my original code is different and huge which just uses the input for other purpose not printing to output

Comment: @JeevansaiJinne: Spend many days to read more about [operating systems](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)

Comment: Looks like some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). Do you want to read & write a disk file, or do you want to make your *program1* and *program2* communicate?

Comment: i want both programs to communicate

Comment: Then you don't need a file, but you do need to spend several days in reading more about operating systems in general and Linux or POSIX programming in particular. I gave many references.

Comment: @JeevansaiJinne *i want both programs to communicate* Then you don't just need a file, you don't want to use a file.  Since you might not know where to begin looking at the references provided, try starting here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe  A named pipe is like a file in that it has a name in a file system so you can use `open()`, `fopen()` and similar on it, but it only holds the data in order to pass it immediately on to a reading process.  You could say it *pipes* data from one process to another.

Answer (score 4):

The most basic version of your code needs to reset the file stream status when it encounters EOF and then sleep for a while.  For example, assuming POSIX and using only the simplest (most ubiquitous) functions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char filename[] = "gbbct1.seq";
    FILE *fptr = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fptr == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to open file '%s' for reading\b", filename);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (1)
    {
        int c;
        while ((c = fgetc(fptr)) != EOF)
            fputc(c, stdout);

        clearerr(fptr);
        sleep(1);
    }
    /*NOTREACHED*/
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

The [`sleep()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sleep.html) function sleeps for an integral number of seconds; if you want sub-second sleeps, you can consider [`usleep()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/usleep.html),
[`nanosleep()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nanosleep.html), [`timer_create()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/timer_create.html) and relatives, etc.

I have a program I call `dribbler` (because it dribbles data to its output):

```
Usage: dribbler [-hlntV][-s nap.time][-r std.dev][-f outfile][-i infile][-m message][-o openstr][-F format]
  -V           Print version information and exit
  -f outfile   Write to named file (dribbler.out)
  -h           Print this help message and exit
  -i infile    Read lines from input file
  -l           Loop back to start of input file on EOF
  -m message   Write message on each line of output
  -n           Number lines read from input file
  -o openstr   Flags passed to fopen() (a+)
  -s nap.time  Sleep for given interval between writes (1.000 second)
  -r std.dev   Randomize the time (Gaussian around nap.time with std.dev)
  -t           Write to standard output instead of file
  -F format    Printf format to use instead of %zu
```

I used:

```
$ dribbler -s 3 -r 1.3 -f gbbct1.seq &
[1] 81129
$
```

to write to the control file that `program2` is coded to read.  I then ran `program2` on it, and it produced the outputs as it proceeded.

It's hard to show the time sequence on SO.  I have another program (the story of my life) called `tstamp` which reads lines of input and prints them with a timestamp prefixed to the line:

```
Usage: tstamp [-hV][-f num][-F format]
  -f num  Number of fractional digits (0, 3, 6, 9)
  -h      Print this help message and exit
  -F fmt  Time format (strftime(3)) to use
  -V      Print version information and exit
```

I tried modifying `program2.c` to set line buffered mode on my Mac (macOS Sierra 10.12.5, GCC 7.1.0), by adding the line below before the `while` loop in `program2.c`, but it was effectively ignored, somewhat to my surprise and chagrin:

```
setvbuf(fptr, 0, _IOLBF, 0);
```

So, I rewrote the `while` loop as:

```
    while ((c = fgetc(fptr)) != EOF)
    {
        fputc(c, stdout);
        if (c == '\n')
            fflush(stdout);
    }
```

Then I was able to run `dribbler` in the background, and `program2 | tstamp -f 3` to get output like:

```
$ program2 | tstamp -f 3
2017-06-03 23:52:44.836: 0: message written to file
2017-06-03 23:52:44.836: 1: message written to file
2017-06-03 23:52:44.836: 2: message written to file
2017-06-03 23:52:44.836: 3: message written to file
[…more similar lines with the same time stamp…]
2017-06-03 23:52:44.836: 22: message written to file
2017-06-03 23:52:44.836: 23: message written to file
2017-06-03 23:52:44.836: 24: message written to file
2017-06-03 23:52:44.836: 25: message written to file
2017-06-03 23:52:50.859: 26: message written to file
2017-06-03 23:52:54.866: 27: message written to file
2017-06-03 23:52:58.880: 28: message written to file
2017-06-03 23:53:02.888: 29: message written to file
2017-06-03 23:53:05.902: 30: message written to file
2017-06-03 23:53:07.907: 31: message written to file
2017-06-03 23:53:09.913: 32: message written to file
2017-06-03 23:53:12.925: 33: message written to file
2017-06-03 23:53:14.935: 34: message written to file
2017-06-03 23:53:15.938: 35: message written to file
2017-06-03 23:53:19.954: 36: message written to file
2017-06-03 23:53:21.964: 37: message written to file
2017-06-03 23:53:23.972: 38: message written to file
^C
$ kill %1
[1]+  Terminated: 15          dribbler -s 3 -r 1.3 -f gbbct1.seq
$
```

You can see that I'd had `dribbler` running for a while when I started `program2` (it got modified and recompiled — part of my chagrin), so there was quite a lot of date to read immediately (hence the multiple lines with the timestamp `2017-06-03 23:52:44.836:`), but then it was waiting on `dribbler` to write more, and as you can see, it sometimes waited nearly 6 seconds between lines, and other times about 1 second, and various intervals in between.  The gaps are made more uniform by `program2` sleeping for a second at a time.  (Yes, I wrote these tools to help answer questions on SO — but `dribbler` and `tstamp` both pre-date this question by months.)

Comment: could you explain how can i use http://c.happycodings.com/c-on-unix/code9.html for my problem

Comment: Not really; I've not seen `spawnl()` before and Google isn't helping much.  Since I don't know what that does, I can't help you interpret it.  (Maybe it originates on [QNX](http://comp.unix.programmer.narkive.com/qy7REFrB/qnx-spawnl-port-to-linux) — and there's [`posix_spawn()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawn.html) which is related but different.  Have fun — when you find the docs, please let me know.)

Answer (score 2):

> I have two programs: one (program1) writes to a file continuously, and I want the other program (program2) to read the file continuously.

What happens then is platform-specific. BTW, the mere ability to run several programs at once (in several [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing))) is provided by the [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) (and is *not* defined in, since outside of, the [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)) standard). Read [*Operating Systems : Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) (freely downloadable chapters).

<sup>IIRC, on Windows (that I don't know and never used) that is not allowed to happen (one of the programs would be blocked or would have its file open fail).</sup>

However, if on Linux with a native local file system (such as Ext4), you could consider using [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) facilities (which won't work with remote file systems à la NFS, and probably won't work on FAT filesystems like e.g. some USB key; but you need to check).

> Basically, I want the output of program1 to be used as the input of program2. Is there any way to read and write in RAM instead of file as disk read costs more time.

<sup>(I am supposing you wrote both *program1* and *program2*, or at least have their source code and can modify it)</sup>

BTW, application programs don't read *directly* from RAM; they work in [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) and each [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) has its own [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space). See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/367995/50557).

You surely want to have some [**inter-process communications**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication), which are provided by your operating system.

On Linux there are many ways of doing that (you should **read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)** whose chapters are freely downloadable). I suggest considering some [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html), or some [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) (if both running programs can be started from a common process), or some [unix(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) sockets.
You surely need to multiplex for I/O (in both processes) e.g. by having some [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) around a [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html).

[Windows also has inter-process communication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx) facilities. But I don't know them.

<sup>(I strongly recommend to spend a few days reading, notably [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) or some other similar book, before writing a single line of code. You lack an overall picture on OSes and on Linux)</sup>

I would recommend using a [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html), or else some named [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html), or else some [unix(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) socket. You could then write code portable on all [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) systems. I don't recommend to use a file and [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html)  (which is complex and Linux specific). See also [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html).

You might find some framework libraries (e.g. [Glib](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk-tutorial/stable/c2023.html) from GTK, [QtCore](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-index.html), [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/), [libevent](http://libevent.org/), [0mq](http://zeromq.org/)) to help you write portable code able to run on many platforms.

Comment: There are tail programs for Windows, so there must be a way to make it work. Not something I've done recently enough to remember though.

Comment: Well, you get my vote because you actually suggest sane inter-process comms and/or inotify instead of a misuse of Sleep() calls.